# ROR3: Why is this not saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, save

This functionality used to work but has suddenly stopped and I have no idea why. I've made changes before I ran the tests but, having retraced my steps I don't know what has changed. Can a fresh pair of eyes tell me why this is saving the posts but not the locations?

*Model Post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list, :locations_attributes
 has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

*Controller Posts_controller.rb *

```
class PostsController < ::Blogit::ApplicationController

...     

def new
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])
  @location = @post.locations.build
end

def update
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

def create
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

end
```

*View _form.html.erb*

```
<%= nested_form_for(@post, :html=> {:multipart => true, :class=> "new_blog_post", :id=> "new_blog_post"}) do |f| %>

 ...

<%= field do %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Give your post a title", :class=>"span12" %>
<% end %>
<%= field do %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write something here...", :id=>"blog-text", :class=>"span12" %>
 <% end %>

<%= field id: "new_blog_post_tag_field" do %>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags" %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list, placeholder: "tag one, tag two, etc..." %>
<% end %>

<%= f.label :search_locations, "Add locations to your post" %>
   <%= render :partial => 'search_locations', :locals => { :f => f }  %>

 <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a location", :locations %></p>

<%= actions do %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn", :disable_with => 'Uploading Image...' %> or 
<%= link_to("cancel", @post.new_record? ? root_path : post_path(@post)) %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

*Form Partial _search_locations.html.erb*

```
 <%= f.fields_for :locations do |m| %>


 <%= m.text_field :name,:class=>"localename", :id=>"appendedInput", :placeholder=> "Name of the location", :autocomplete => "off" %>


 <span class="add-on"><%= m.link_to_remove do %><i class='icon-trash'></i></span><%end%>


 <% end %>
```

And the actual submission in the logs comes up as this:

```
Started PUT "/blog/posts/51-hong-kong" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-06 17:41:00 +0000
Processing by Blogit::PostsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"s+2117Qi/HzO/D/ORINhqHChMJR3S5XK7y/s3rq3dnc=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Hong 
Kong ", "body"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In orci elit,  
rhoncus quis interdum vel, interdum non nulla. Phasellus nec massa lorem. Duis malesuada   
pellentesque orci, accumsan mollis augue aliquam mollis. Pellentesque luctus orci in enim 
hendrerit adipiscing. Mauris tempor tortor in leo posuere tristique.", "tag_list"=>"", 
"locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false",    
"name"=>"London","longitude"=>"-0.1276831", "latitude"=>"51.5073346"}}},
"_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "name"=>"London", "legname"=>"London", "longitude"=>"-0.1276831",
"latitude"=>"51.5073346", "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"51-hong-kong"}
```

Why is this saving the post but not the locations info?

Comment: you should have posted update method from your controller instead of create method, as you have provided log for update method.

Comment: Hi Prem, thanks for your comment. I've added in the update method. I don't think that's the issue, however as locations don't save in the database regardless of whether I'm updating or creating new. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was a stray bit of code in the model.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `fields_for`, try replace:

```
<%= render :partial => 'search_locations', :locals => { :f => f }  %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a location", :locations %></p>

<%= actions do %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn", :disable_with => 'Uploading Image...' %> or 
<%= link_to("cancel", @post.new_record? ? root_path : post_path(@post)) %>
```

With:

```
<% f.fields_for :locations do |location| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'search_locations', :locals => { :f => location }  %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn", :disable_with => 'Uploading Image...' %> or 
<%= link_to("cancel", @post.new_record? ? root_path : post_path(@post)) %>
```

Comment: Hi Kien, I do have a fields_for in the partial. I tried it your way and got an error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what error you got? What is this `nested_form_for`? just `form_for`.